# ANDROID Periodic servicecall

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I'll start by explaining the app that i'm currently working on.

i'm developing an Android app that displays a schema, a schema consists of tasks, and a task can have a subtask and so on. i'ts for kids who have authism and the purpose of the app is stimulating the independence of a child.

How i see it: the app does a servicecall to the server **every night**, receives a new JSON file with the schema for the next day. That JSON file needs to be parsed to the correct domain objects. The app has more functionality but thats beyond the scope of my question.

I'm having troubles implementing the correct solution for the problem mentioned above.
What i think i need to do:

Set an alarm that repeats every night via the AlarmManager. When the alarm goes of, the AlarmReceiver starts an Asynctask. In the asyncTask the JSON needs to be requested and parsed.

is this way of thinking the correct way? 
I have also read about services, they can perform tasks in the background. But services stop when the phone is shut down.

Should I implement services for activation the asynctask? or should i start the service when the alarm goes off?

i hope i'm clear about my issues with implementing the correct solution for this problem.

Comment: for the basic functionality, yes, what you have outlined will work and I've done similar on my apps.   An alarm fires up a service which does the downloading/parsing in an asynctask at night. That's perfect.    Getting it to start up again after a reboot, that's a slightly different answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use BOOT_COMPLETED Reciever and start your Activity inside

Edit: Use code like below

```
public class MyBroadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(startIntent);
}
```

}
And in your Manifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver">  
<intent-filter>  
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, also for pointing out that the service should start after a reboot. 
One more question: should i stop the service after the completion of the asyncTask or should i give that option to the android system?

Comment: I'd leave the service running. If your alarm was set, it should wake up and do the asynctask each day at the same time and if the service is already started it will just restart. If not, it will start the service